# How to Sign in to SIP SERVER with Username and Password

Tags: sip, voip

I am new to developing for .NET and trying to develop a Basic SIP Client (Softphone) in Visual Studio 2010 without any SDK.

The softphone will work in following steps.

1. User will signin to my website using that Softphone (SIP Client)
2. After Signing in, Softphone will display Users Current Balance and Call History etc.
   This balance and call history is at my end/server/website.
3. Than a user dials a number.
4. My Softphone SIP Client will signin to my sip provider server via my username and password and will make a call.

I have successfully developed Steps 1-3. 
Now i am unable to sign in to my sip server as i have no idea where to through signin request and to establish a call.

Comment: You need to read the SIP specification (rfc 3261 and a bazillion others), then implement those protocols.

Comment: @nos will you please refer me to some guide links to start from ?

Comment: @nos: You mean find out who's already implemented SIP, surely?!

Comment: @Frank Shearar That would be the sane thing, but he OP already stated "without any SDK".

Answer (score 0):

You can download and compile the pjsip ,then call the dll from your c# code.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to read [SIP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261) and [RTP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550) and likely [G711 payload](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5391) and a bunch of others and implement them... Or use an SDK, because that's a project for at least a few months of full time work otherwise.